# Maven install beanstalk error

Tags: maven

I am starting out with Maven, following a book. I'm using 3.2.1 on Ubuntu. I have run the following commands:

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch03 -DartifactId=simple -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook

mvn install

I then get a beanstalk error. Essentially, I don't have Amazon credentials. I understand the concepts surrounding Maven. What if I don't want to use Amazon services? Is this really necessary?

 `[INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [WARNING] 
 [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch03:simple:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
 [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 143, column 12
 [WARNING] 
 [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
 [WARNING] 
 [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
 [WARNING] 
 [INFO]

 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Building simple 1.0-SNAPSHOT
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- beanstalk-maven-plugin:0.2.8:expose-security-credentials (expose-security-credentials) @ simple ---
 [WARNING] FAILURE
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Settings for serverId ('aws.amazon.com') not found. See http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/security.html for more information`

Comment: Can you place the error message in more detail? It helps to figure it out

Comment: What's really perplexing is that I did exactly the same thing on a Windows XP box a few days ago and had no problems. I haven't configured a thing; I assumed the default config would work.

Comment: Something is fundamentally wrong. It created a WAR project, for one. Looking at the warnings, it is missing a basic plugin. I also downloaded 3.1.1, but it giving the same errors. I suspect simply downloading and decompressing is having some sort of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably used the `elasticbeanstalk` archetypes. A short reason (as it seems you're just learning Maven) is to edit your pom and remove the `<plugin/>` sections for `br.com.ingenieux` groupId.

Hope it helps

#### For those who care about the little details on why did it fail

Since release 1.3.x (a few weeks ago), we dropped the usage of `aws.accessKey` and `aws.secretKey`. The warnings were there for more than two years in fact :)

Reason: Many projects on github were leaking AWS Keys

Instead, set those as environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) and (AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) or use encryption - see [this doc](http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/security.html) for an overview